# Parsing/Querying Map in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In my Jenkins pipeline, I am capturing status of each stage in jenkins pipeline.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
rstages=[:]

pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'RDama-Machine'
    }
    stages {
         stage('Validate Fail fast') {
             parallel {
                stage('stage A') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage A started'
                        echo 'stage A Ended'
                    }
                    post {
                                always {
                                        stageresults()
                                    }
                                } //post
                }
                stage('stage B C') {
                    stages {
                      stage('stage B') {
                        steps {
                        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                            echo 'stage B started'
                            sleep 5
                            bat 'exit 1'
                            echo 'stage B Ended' //will not execute because of above sh return
                            }
                        }
                        post {
                            always {
                                    stageresults()
                                }
                            } //post
                        }
                        stage('stage C') {
                            steps {
                                echo 'stage C started'
                                sleep 10
                                echo 'stage C Ended' //will not execute because of above stage fail
                            }
                            post {
                                always {
                                        stageresults()
                                    }
                                } //post
                            }
                        stage('Validate-Status') {
                            steps {
                                script {
                                    println rstages
                                    }//script
                            }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 stage('stage D') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage D started'
                        echo 'stage D Ended' //May complete before Stage A fails
                    }
                    post {
                                always {
                                        stageresults()
                                    }
                                } //post
                }
            }
        }   
         stage('final stage sequential') {
             steps {
                 script {
                     echo "The complete run!"
                 }
             }
             post {
                                always {
                                        stageresults()
                                    }
                                } //post
         }
    }
}
def stageresults(){
    script{
        //println "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
        //println "current stage name is: ${env.STAGE_NAME}"
        def cstage="${env.STAGE_NAME}".replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+","")
        //println cstage
        //println rstages."${env.STAGE_NAME}" = "'${currentBuild.result}'"
        rstages.put((cstage), "${currentBuild.result}")
        println rstages
        //if("${currentBuild.result}" == "FAILURE") {
        //println "printing logs for failed stage"
        //}
    }
}
```

and when I print output `println rstages` i see below.

```
{stage A=SUCCESS, stage D=SUCCESS, stage B=FAILURE, stage C=SUCCESS, final stage sequential=SUCCESS}
```

First thing is, when we write elements into array, not sure why it is displaying in curly{} braces, instead of square[] braces.

Second thing is, for each key, if there is any value associated as "FAILURE", I want to print that key name as failed. For example, in above list "stage B" is failed.

Can you help with it. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like this isn’t a list, it’s  a map. Call .class on it to find out what it is.

Comment: Or if `.class` returns null (as it usually does for maps as it's interpreted as a query for key `class`), try `.getClass()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `rstages=[:]` is a declaration of a [Map](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#Collections-Maps). In Jenkins pipeline scripts, maps are printed with curly braces (despite in regular Groovy jdk `toString()` is implemented to print maps with brackets).
2. In your example, keys associated with "FAILURE" can be printed this way:

   ```
   rstages.findAll { it.value == 'FAILURE' }.each {
       println "stage ${it.key} failed"
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Vitalii. Appreciate your help.